# How to derive colour of text in element using Selenium?

Tags: java, css, selenium

Is it possible to derive (i.e. by automatically applying all inherited CSS styles and, if it is possible - JS scripts as well) **colour** of the text in given `WebElement`?

For instance, I want to detect colour of text in each visible element:

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
List<WebElement> elements = body.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
for (WebElement we : elements) {
    if (we.isDisplayed()) {
       // ... colour of text in "we" element?
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do?

P.S. I realise that each `we` element can contain nested elements and colour inside them can differ. But let's simplify the issue and consider each `we` as element without nested tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getCssValue()` something like below:

```
element.getCssValue("color")
```

which in your case will be

```
we.getCssValue("color")
```

For reference -  http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-get-css-values-using-webdriver